# Django and ElasticBeanstalk: Internal server error, HTTP/2 protocol will be inactive

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to deploy my Django app in eb. I've created the environment on eb and even though all things seems good internal server error happens.

I was just following the tutorial on official site. 
I already committed my `requirements.txt` and `.ebextensions` to my git. 
I set the environement variables on eb configuration.

But there's an internal server error. And also `eb open` doesn't work.

`.ebextensions/django.config`

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
   WSGIPath: config/wsgi.py
```

`settings.py`

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*"]
```

I'm still using `sqlite3` on local.

`error.log` is like this

```
[Mon Sep 17 03:26:31.366607 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 10621] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Mon Sep 17 03:26:32.520377 2018] [suexec:notice] [pid 11711] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Mon Sep 17 03:26:32.536121 2018] [so:warn] [pid 11711] AH01574: module wsgi_module is already loaded, skipping
[Mon Sep 17 03:26:32.538258 2018] [http2:warn] [pid 11711] AH10034: The mpm module (prefork.c) is not supported by mod_http2. The mpm determines how things are processed in your server. HTTP/2 has more demands in this regard and the currently selected mpm will just not do. This is an advisory warning. Your server will continue to work, but the HTTP/2 protocol will be inactive.
[Mon Sep 17 03:26:32.538272 2018] [http2:warn] [pid 11711] AH02951: mod_ssl does not seem to be enabled
[Mon Sep 17 03:26:32.538809 2018] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 11711] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Mon Sep 17 03:26:32.538869 2018] [:warn] [pid 11711] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/3.6.2.
[Mon Sep 17 03:26:32.538875 2018] [:warn] [pid 11711] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/3.6.5.
[Mon Sep 17 03:26:32.541103 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 11711] AH00163: Apache/2.4.33 (Amazon) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/3.6.5 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Sep 17 03:26:32.541124 2018] [core:notice] [pid 11711] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
[Mon Sep 17 03:26:35.694597 2018] [:error] [pid 11716] /opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/storages/backends/s3boto3.py:282: UserWarning: The default behavior of S3Boto3Storage is insecure and will change in django-storages 2.0. By default files and new buckets are saved with an ACL of 'public-read' (globally publicly readable). Version 2.0 will default to using the bucket's ACL. To opt into the new behavior set AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = None, otherwise to silence this warning explicitly set AWS_DEFAULT_ACL.
[Mon Sep 17 03:26:35.694625 2018] [:error] [pid 11716]   "The default behavior of S3Boto3Storage is insecure and will change "
[Mon Sep 17 03:26:35.763182 2018] [:error] [pid 11716] /opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/storages/backends/s3boto3.py:282: UserWarning: The default behavior of S3Boto3Storage is insecure and will change in django-storages 2.0. By default files and new buckets are saved with an ACL of 'public-read' (globally publicly readable). Version 2.0 will default to using the bucket's ACL. To opt into the new behavior set AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = None, otherwise to silence this warning explicitly set AWS_DEFAULT_ACL.
[Mon Sep 17 03:26:35.763199 2018] [:error] [pid 11716]   "The default behavior of S3Boto3Storage is insecure and will change "
```

How can I fix this error?

The part caused by `django-storages` solved. But other part is still the same.

```
[Mon Sep 17 06:44:13.104471 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 18559] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Mon Sep 17 06:44:14.259136 2018] [suexec:notice] [pid 19102] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Mon Sep 17 06:44:14.274950 2018] [so:warn] [pid 19102] AH01574: module wsgi_module is already loaded, skipping
[Mon Sep 17 06:44:14.277045 2018] [http2:warn] [pid 19102] AH10034: The mpm module (prefork.c) is not supported by mod_http2. The mpm determines how things are processed in your server. HTTP/2 has more demands in this regard and the currently selected mpm will just not do. This is an advisory warning. Your server will continue to work, but the HTTP/2 protocol will be inactive.
[Mon Sep 17 06:44:14.277059 2018] [http2:warn] [pid 19102] AH02951: mod_ssl does not seem to be enabled
[Mon Sep 17 06:44:14.277619 2018] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 19102] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Mon Sep 17 06:44:14.277677 2018] [:warn] [pid 19102] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/3.6.2.
[Mon Sep 17 06:44:14.277681 2018] [:warn] [pid 19102] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/3.6.5.
[Mon Sep 17 06:44:14.279864 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 19102] AH00163: Apache/2.4.33 (Amazon) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/3.6.5 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Sep 17 06:44:14.279883 2018] [core:notice] [pid 19102] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
```

Comment: can you share the internal server error that you see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the error, the issue is raised by the `django-storages` application. Add this setting to your settings.py should fix the issue.

```
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = None
```

This change will fix the error you are facing now, but maybe there are other issues. Please share more details the next error.

Comment: Did you try to change the settings as I suggested?

Comment: Yes. It must be in the repo

Comment: I do not see any error. Did you update the question?

Comment: Nope, the last lines shows that you are running the apache correctly

Comment: still never successful.. I tried with native Django project but `Not Found
The requested URL / was not found on this server.` this error happens.. I cannot do even as the tutorial does..

Comment: You should share more details about the project and the logs of the error that can be also in the apache logs